# Excel file not loaded correctly

Tags: c#, gembox-spreadsheet

I am using Gembox-spreadsheet to parse excel files with multiple sheets.

I am currently loading a file using the following code:

```
excelFile.LoadXlsx(inputExcel, XlsxOptions.None);
```

where inputExcel is a fullpath. After importing the excel, I try to access its content (for each sheet, parse rows and obtain cell data). The problem here is that after loading the document, in debug mode if I check the values in a sheet, I see this error:

> 'excelFile.Worksheets.ActiveWorksheet.Cells.Value' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'.

However, when I try to retrieve the information from a cell (which contains some info, doesn't matter of which type) it retrieves 0.

Does anybody know why this error occurs and how I can prevent it?

I must mention that the values in the cells are generated through formulas, from a separate worksheet. Could this be why the values are not loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the problem. Because the cell values are obtained through formulas, when loading the file you must set XlsxOptions.PreserveWorksheetRecords (for xls) or XlsOptions.PreserveKeepOpen (for xlsx)